# Cannot figure out how to convert from String to int?

Tags: java

I'm working on an assignment and run into a wall I can't get past.

I cannot figure out how to take in this user selection to continue my code.

Maybe I'm over thinking, but I'm at a loss and have started at this far too long lol

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Arrays;

  public class DestinationPlanner {

static Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
static int cityDistance,  arrivalCity;
static double gasCost, MPG, totalCost;
static String userContinue, userSelection, departCity;

static double [][] cityTable = {
    {0, 384, 706, 729, 744, 767, 605, 548, 492, 346},
    {384, 0, 399, 628, 437, 473, 291, 714, 390, 244},
    {706, 399, 0, 877, 47, 605, 110, 1086, 742, 640},
    {729, 628, 877, 0, 914, 384, 825, 395, 259, 406},
    {744, 437, 47, 914, 0, 609, 154, 1123, 780, 685},
    {767, 473, 605, 384, 609, 0, 563, 708, 367, 420},
    {605, 291, 110, 825, 154, 563, 0, 1002, 679, 533},
    {548, 714, 1086, 395, 1123, 708, 1002, 0, 344, 469},
    {492, 390, 742, 259, 780, 367, 679, 344, 0, 146},
    {346, 244, 640, 406, 685, 420, 533, 469, 146, 0},
};

static String [] citySelection = {"Jacksonville, Fl", "Charlotte, NC", "Washington, DC", "Memphis, TN", 
    "Baltimore, MD", "Louisville, KY", "Richmond, VA", "New Orleans, LA", "Birmingham, AL", "Atlanta, GA"
};

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Welcome to the Southeast Destination Planner!"
            + "\nTo help you plan your trip this program will calculate"
            + "\nthe cost to travel between two popular Southeast cities"
            + "\nWill you continue?"
            + "\nEnter 'y' to continiue 'n' to quit");
    userContinue = keyboard.nextLine().toLowerCase();       

    while ((userContinue.equals("y")) & (userContinue.equals("n"))){
        userContinue = keyboard.nextLine().toLowerCase();   
    }
    while (userContinue.equals("n")) {
        System.out.println("The program will now terminate");
        System.exit(0);
    }

    while (userContinue.equals("y")) {

        citySelection();
        carInfo();
        finalCost();

    }

}

private static void citySelection() {
    System.out.println("\nGreat, let's start by determining the city you will be departing");
    System.out.println("\nPlease choose from the following cities");
    System.out.println("[0]  Jacksonville, FL");
    System.out.println("[1]  Charlotte, NC");
    System.out.println("[2]  Washington, DC");
    System.out.println("[3]  Memphis, TNA");
    System.out.println("[4]  Baltimore, MD");
    System.out.println("[5]  Louisville, KY");
    System.out.println("[6]  Richmond, VA");
    System.out.println("[7]  New Orleans, LA");
    System.out.println("[8]  Birmingham, AL");
    System.out.println("[9]  Atlanta, GA");

    System.out.println("\nWhere will your trip begin?");
    departCity = keyboard.nextLine();

    while (!(departCity.equals("1")) && !(departCity.equals("2")) && !(departCity.equals("3")) && 
            !(departCity.equals("4")) && !(departCity.equals("5")) && !(departCity.equals("6")) &&
                !(departCity.equals("7")) && !(departCity.equals("8")) && !(departCity.equals("9")) &&
                        !(departCity.equals("0"))){

        System.out.println("Please enter a number 0 through 9");

    departCity = keyboard.nextLine();
    }
    System.out.println("\nYou have chosen to depart from " + citySelection[departCity]);



}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Integer.parseInt()` to parse to an Integer object.  After that, autoboxing should take care of it, but you'll want to look for the case where you get a null or a 0.  You can also then just check that the number is in range rather than your if statement with 9 different conditions.

Comment: or `Integer.valueOf` if you want an `Integer` instead of an `int` which is returned by `Integer.parseInt`

Comment: Thank you, thank you! This fixed it! I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 3):

Your best bet is to use a scanner in lieu of keyboard.nextLine(). It has a .nextInt() built right it, though it needs to be surrounded in a try catch (just in case the input wasn't a number)

```
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    int result = s.nextInt();
```